# Haskell processing [IO String]

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming, monads

I've got the following function:

```
lines' :: [IO String]
lines' = getLine : lines'
```

I was hoping I could just use all the mighty list functions on
this list, like filter etc. But my knowledge about the IO monad in
haskell is improvable.

The list-of-io_stuff-concept convinced me after using Rx for C#.

Is there any way to do what I want in haskell ? 
Something like:

```
ten_lines :: [IO String]
ten_lines = take 10 lines'

proc_lines :: [IO String]
proc_lines = [ (l, length l) | l <- lines' ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tikhon's solution is the simplest one, but it has one major deficiency: it will not produce any results until processing the entire list and it will overflow if you process too large of a list.

A solution closer to C#'s Rx would be to use a streaming library like `pipes`.

For example, you can define a `Producer` that generates `String`s from user input:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Proxy

lines' :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p String IO r
lines' () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    str <- lift getLine
    respond str
```

Then you can define a stage that takes 10 lines:

```
take' :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => Int -> () -> Pipe p a a m ()
take' n () = runIdentityP $ replicateM_ n $ do
    a <- request ()
    respond a
```

... and then a processing stage:

```
proc :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => () -> Pipe p String (String, Int) m r
proc () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    str <- request ()
    respond (str, length str)
```

... and a final output stage:

```
print' :: (Proxy p, Show a) => () -> Consumer p a IO r
print' () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    a <- request ()
    lift $ print a
```

Now you can compose those into a processing chain and run it:

```
main = runProxy $ lines' >-> take' 10 >-> proc >-> print'
```

... and it will output the processed result instantly after entering each line, rather than providing the result as a batch at the end:

```
$ ./pipes
Apple<Enter>
("Apple",5)
Test<Enter>
("Test",4)
123<Enter>
("123",3)
4<Enter>
("4",1)
5<Enter>
("5",1)
6<Enter>
("6",1)
7<Enter>
("7",1)
8<Enter>
("8",1)
9<Enter>
("9",1)
10<Enter>
("10",2)
$
```

In practice, you don't have to define these pipes yourself.  You can assemble the same chain from components in the `pipes` standard library:

```
>>> runProxy $ stdinS >-> takeB_ 10 >-> mapD (\x -> (x, length x)) >-> printD
<exact same behavior>
```

Comment: Nice, definitely closer to Rx. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There are a whole bunch of normal list functions modified to work with monads in [`Control.Monad`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html). Of particular interest to your question:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
mapM     :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
filterM  :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
foldM    :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
```

(`sequence` and `mapM` are actually exported by the prelude and available by default.)

For example, let's take a look at the type of your `take 10 lines'` example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t take 10 lines'
take 10 lines' :: [IO String]
```

We want to turn this `[IO String]` into a single `IO [String]` action. This is exactly what `sequence` does! We can tell this by the type signature. So:

```
sequence $ take 10 lines'
```

will do what you want.

Most of these functions also have a version ending in `_`, like `sequence_`. This has exactly the same effect as the normal function except it throws away the result, returning `()` instead. That is, `sequence_ :: [m a] -> m ()`. This is a good choice whenever you don't actually care about the result for two reasons: it's more explicit about your intentions and the performance can be better.

So if you wanted to *print* 10 lines rather than get them, you would write something like this:

```
printLines = putStrLn "foo" : printLines

main = sequence_ $ take 10 printLines
```

Comment: ah, thats exactly what I was searching for! Thx!!

Comment: Also, have a look at [`replicateM`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) and [`replicateM_`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM_).